# iOS In-App purchases with sandbox not working

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

What is the correct way to get sandbox in-app purchases working on iOS?

I either get "Cannot connect to iTunes store" or a infinity loop that asks for my password.

I read, when I add users to TestFlight, they become sandbox users automatically for "that app", which didn't seem to be right. So I created multiple sandbox users in iTunes connect and tried to buy something in-app.

There are really long pauses (>10sec) between every pop-up of the purchase, even tho I'm on a really fast internet connection.

Sometimes I get simply an error along the way, that I can't connect to the iTunes store.

Sometimes I get asked about my password multiple times in extra pop-ups that open while the "regular" purchase pop-ups are shown.

Comment: Sadly, sandbox IAPs are **this** bad. On top of all of this, they flat out don't work as they should on simulators; you should use an actual device instead.

Comment: I use an iPhone 6+, on the simulator I got the cannot connect error right away

Answer (score 1):

In-App purchase sandbox servers don't seem to work today... I have the same error, while it worked well before with the same code. You should retry later.

Comment: This better be a comment.